# How to create 3D trapezoid in three.js?

Tags: 3d, three.js, geometry, 3d-modelling

I'm working on a small animation in **three.js** that has a few basic 3D models in it and one of them I'm struggling with is "**trapezoid**".

So far I was only able to create truncated pyramid with the help of THREE.CylinderGeometry which base sides are always the same.

```
// radiusAtTop, radiusAtBottom, height, segmentsAroundRadius, segmentsAlongHeight
const dash_geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 140, 150, 50, 4, 1 )
const dash_material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(dash_settings.material)
const dash_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(dash_geometry, dash_material)
```

But I need an object with different width, height, depth as in the picture.

[image: trapezoid / truncated cuboid pyramid]

Can anyone at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have a look at this [forum thread](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/create-mesh-geometry-from-array-of-8-corners-vertices/2116/12?u=prisoner849).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a trapezoid whose base is 1 x 1 and height is 1 like so:

```
var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 0.8 / Math.sqrt( 2 ), 1 / Math.sqrt( 2 ), 1, 4, 1 ); // size of top can be changed
```

It is easier if you rotate the geometry before continuing:

```
geometry.rotateY( Math.PI / 4 );
```

Likely, you will want to recompute the vertex normals for 'flat' shading:

```
geometry = geometry.toNonIndexed(); // removes shared vertices
geometry.computeVertexNormals(); // normals will be 'flat' normals
```

Then, when you create the mesh, you can scale it:

```
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

mesh.scale.set( width, height, depth );
```

three.js r.126

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, I thought CylinderGeometry would be the way but couldn't make its sides different sizes, scale.set() did it.

Thanks, it works!

Comment: How would you best make a trapezoid where width differs from depth? You could obviously scale it, but then the angles of the sides also changes.